# How to fix an iPhone 4S with disabled iCloud settings?

Tags: ios, icloud

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 7.1.1 and my iCloud is disabled (greyed out) in settings.  How do I enable it if I can't select it?

Answer (score 1):

Why is it grey out?
In **Settings-General-Restrictions(password required)-Accounts**
(Current Value:Don't Allow Changes)

If the value is Don't Allow Changes,the icloud in Settings will be disabled automatically.

---

To enable Settings>icloud
Go to:**Settings-General-Restrictions(password required)-Accounts**
Select "Allow Changes"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the “Activation Lock” is disabled due to the phone still being connected to someone else’s iCloud account via “Find My iPhone”. If you purchased this legitimately—not stolen—perhaps the user did not remove the phone from their “Find My iPhone” settings in iCloud? More details [straight from Apple on this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702):

> If you’re no longer using an iOS device or Mac, you can remove it from
>   Find My iPhone. When you remove a device, it’s removed from your Find
>   My iPhone devices list, and if your device has iOS 7 or later,
>   Activation Lock is also turned off.
>
> Before giving away or selling your iOS device, be sure to erase your
>   content and settings (in Settings > General > Reset > Erase All
>   Content and Settings). When you erase your content, Find My iPhone and
>   Activation Lock are also turned off. For more information, see the
>   Apple Support article What to do before selling or giving away your
>   iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.

Also, [additional details here](http://recomhub.com/blog/how-to-unlock-activation-lock-icloud-iphone-no-password/).

> These devices that have “Find My iPhone” activated can’t have any of
>   their Apple devices restored without the login password to your Apple
>   ID. This Activation lock created by Apple was done to help track your
>   iPhone and to help the reduction of stolen iPhones being sold on the
>   black market. Some negatives of this service is for iPhone owners who
>   have purchased their iPhone or iPad from a third-party reseller who
>   had activated “Find My iPhone” and don’t know the old password to turn
>   off the Activation lock, thus having iPhone iCloud locked.